# What does the time in pgadmin mean?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

on the right bottom,like the pic below: what does the 8311ms mean, it's different from the \timing or explain analyze time.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is the duration of the query, see this link to [pgadmin docs](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/query.html), it states:

The status line will show how long the last query took to complete. If a dataset was returned, not only the elapsed time for server execution is displayed, but also the time to retrieve the data from the server to the Data Output page.

Further [documentation](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/main.html) from the same site supports this statement.